# How to change the color of the SVG when hovering over the image?

Tags: html, css, svg, hyperlink

I have an image (with a link) and the YouTube logo in the center.

I will want the YouTube logo to be red when I hover the image.

Currently it is not working. I have to hover over the logo for the color to change, I want it to change as soon as I hover over the image.

Here is an example (hover over the video at the bottom of the page) :

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9057455?hl=fr

Here is my code :

```css
#youtube-remote,
#youtube-remote .youtube-remote-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#youtube-remote svg {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}

#youtube-remote svg:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="youtube-remote">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="youtube-remote-container">
      <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/ZLga1SIE1HA/maxresdefault.jpg" width="1280" height="720" alt="" loading="lazy">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-youtube" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8.051 1.999h.089c.822.003 4.987.033 6.11.335a2.01 2.01 0 0 1 1.415 1.42c.101.38.172.883.22 1.402l.01.104.022.26.008.104c.065.914.073 1.77.074 1.957v.075c-.001.194-.01 1.108-.082 2.06l-.008.105-.009.104c-.05.572-.124 1.14-.235 1.558a2.007 2.007 0 0 1-1.415 1.42c-1.16.312-5.569.334-6.18.335h-.142c-.309 0-1.587-.006-2.927-.052l-.17-.006-.087-.004-.171-.007-.171-.007c-1.11-.049-2.167-.128-2.654-.26a2.007 2.007 0 0 1-1.415-1.419c-.111-.417-.185-.986-.235-1.558L.09 9.82l-.008-.104A31.4 31.4 0 0 1 0 7.68v-.123c.002-.215.01-.958.064-1.778l.007-.103.003-.052.008-.104.022-.26.01-.104c.048-.519.119-1.023.22-1.402a2.007 2.007 0 0 1 1.415-1.42c.487-.13 1.544-.21 2.654-.26l.17-.007.172-.006.086-.003.171-.007A99.788 99.788 0 0 1 7.858 2h.193zM6.4 5.209v4.818l4.157-2.408L6.4 5.209z"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this `#youtube-remote img:hover svg { fill: #ff0000; }`

Comment: @MB Thanks, I just tested, but the hover has no effect

Comment: @MB_ Ok thank you, I found `#youtube-remote a:hover svg { fill: #ff0000; }`

Comment: @MB_ One last question, I am using this svg https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/youtube/ do you know how i can make the inside (the triangle) in white ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the :hover pseudoclass onto the image instead of the svg. Also, you should use 'fill' instead of background-color for svgs to properly fill in only the path :)

If you want the middle triangle to be white permanently (like in the link's video), you'll need to add another path to the svg and fill that with white.

EDIT: added the center play button path (just copied the SVG from the referenced page + its viewbox) and changed opacity when hovered.

```css
#youtube-remote,
#youtube-remote .youtube-remote-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#youtube-remote svg {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#youtube-remote:hover svg {
    opacity: 1;
}

#youtube-remote:hover .play-outer {
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
   

 <div id="youtube-remote">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="youtube-remote-container">
      <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/ZLga1SIE1HA/maxresdefault.jpg" width="1280" height="720" alt="" loading="lazy">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 68 48">
        <path class="play-outer" d="M66.52,7.74c-0.78-2.93-2.49-5.41-5.42-6.19C55.79,.13,34,0,34,0S12.21,.13,6.9,1.55 C3.97,2.33,2.27,4.81,1.48,7.74C0.06,13.05,0,24,0,24s0.06,10.95,1.48,16.26c0.78,2.93,2.49,5.41,5.42,6.19 C12.21,47.87,34,48,34,48s21.79-0.13,27.1-1.55c2.93-0.78,4.64-3.26,5.42-6.19C67.94,34.95,68,24,68,24S67.94,13.05,66.52,7.74z"/>
        <path d="M 45,24 27,14 27,34" fill="white"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect, but I didn't understand how to color the triangle in white and how to make the logo slightly transparent when it is not hovered over https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/youtube/

Comment: @zoulou66 there you go :)